# assignment to expression with array type error in C functions used in if statements

Tags: c, function, void

so i was trying to make a choice-like code where you type something to get a command to run and you type something else to run an other command,and i tried to do this with functions with the void command since i am trying to learn and figure out how to use it but for some reason i keep getting this error message that i don't really understand what it means or how to solve it (this might be a obvious thing but i am still learning soooo)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    char commandA[20];    
    char commandB[20];
    char click [20];

    scanf("%s",click);
    if (click=commandA){
        command1();
    } else if (click=commandB){
        command2();
    }
}

void command1(){
    printf("i don't know what to type here ");
}
void command2(){
    printf("i don't know what to type here x2");
}
}
```

i expect to be able to type commandA and get the first printf message and i expect to able to type commandB to get the second printf message and here are the other warnings and errors i got :

```
|11|error: assignment to expression with array type|
|12|error: assignment to expression with array type|
|11|warning: implicit declaration of function 'command1' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
|12|warning: implicit declaration of function 'command2' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
|14|warning: conflicting types for 'command1'|
|16|warning: conflicting types for 'command2'|
```

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparison. But if you want to compare strings, you have to use `strcmp()`.

Comment: You cannot directly compare arrays by value in C.  You must use a function or compare each individual element yourself.  BTW, thank you for enabling warnings.  It will serve you well in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is because you're using `=` instead of `==` in your `if` statements. `=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparing for equality. But in order to compare strings, you have to use the `strcmp()` function; if you use `==`, it just compares the addresses of the arrays, not the contents.

The error about implicit declarations is because you put the definitions of `command1` and `command2` after `main()`. C requires functions to be defined or declared before they're used, so you either have to move `main()` down, or put function prototypes before it.

You also need to initializze `commandA` and `commandB`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void command1(){
    printf("i don't know what to type here ");
}
void command2(){
    printf("i don't know what to type here x2");
}

int main()
{
    char commandA[20] = "cmdA";    
    char commandB[20] = "cmdB";
    char click [20];

    scanf("%s",click);
    if (strcmp(click, commandA) == 0){
        command1();
    } else if (strcmp(click, commandB) == 0){
        command2();
    }
}
```